# Dropdownlist filter inside details view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entitydatasource

I have a **drop down list** (very long, over 100 items) inside the **insert item template view** for a details view. I would like to add a text box and button (search feature) so i can filter this list but i get the following error.

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

I created two entity datasource, one with a where clause and the other one without. When I hit search, the code behind (button click event) switches the datasource to the one with the where clause and parameter but i get the error above. Any advice on how to go about doing this?

```
Dim aa As DropDownList = DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1")
 aa.DataSourceID = ""
 aa.DataSource = EmpPersonalInfoLOV1   
 aa.DataBind()
```

EDITED
 **Change aa.DataSource from a string to EmpPersonalInfoLOV1 (the name of the datasource)**

***EDIT #2***
More info requested by users..

**Datasource # 1 Code**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EmpPersonalInfoLOV" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="sspEntities" 
                    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Employee_Personal_Info" 
                    EntityTypeFilter="" 
                    Select="it.[Emp_id], it.[Employee_No_FastPay], it.[Surname] + ' '+ it.[Firstname] As FullName" 
                    Where="">
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**Datasource # 2 Code**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EmpPersonalInfoLOV1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="sspEntities" 
                    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Employee_Personal_Info" 
                    Select="it.[Emp_id], it.[Employee_No_FastPay], it.[Surname] + ' '+ it.[Firstname] As FullName" 
                    Where="it.Surname like '%' + @Name + '%'">
                    <WhereParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtBx1" DbType="String" 
                            DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" Name="Name"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    </WhereParameters>
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: I haven't done this in a while but I believe the `DataSource` should be an object not a string?

Comment: how do i make an entity datasource and object. Im sorry, im new to this, any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You are setting aa.DataSource to a string value. You should set it to the actual datasource object

Comment: I still get the same error.. it didnt work

Comment: You said you have two entity data sources. I assume DS2 is the ID of your datasouce, but you want the object, not just a string with the id. So, remove the quotation marks and it might work better.

Comment: You will have to supply some more code, otherwise it is very hard to understand what you are trying to do. Can you supply the code for your datasources?

Comment: Also, remove aa.DataSourceID = ""

Comment: @TheJonasPersson i did that and it still got the same error.

Comment: Did you also remove `aa.DataSourceID = ""`? What object type is EmpPersonalInfoLOV1?

Comment: @TheJonasPersson it is the second entity datasource and yes i remove the aa.DataSourceID = ""

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using the correct `PropertyName` on your `EntityDataSource`. Since you are getting the value from a textbox, the property you are getting is Text. Try this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EmpPersonalInfoLOV1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="sspEntities" 
                EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Employee_Personal_Info" 
                Select="it.[Emp_id], it.[Employee_No_FastPay], it.[Surname] + ' '+ it.[Firstname] As FullName" 
                Where="it.Surname like '%' + @Name + '%'">
                <WhereParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtBx1" DbType="String" Type="String" DefaultValue="" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" />
                </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Also, when you are using the like in your where clause, you really don't need two data objects. When the textbox is empty the query will select all.

Comment: The Type property of parameter 'Name' cannot be set when the DbType property is set.

Comment: I dont think the datasource is the problem. If i create a duplicate of the first DS and try to switch it to the duplicate..still gives the error. I think it has to do with the databind() method.

Comment: Well, I'd go with Type then, but the more important difference is PropertyName.

Comment: I am still getting the 
**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. You could try changing to objectdatasource instead of entitydatasource. I read somewhere that other ppl have had issues with EDS.

Comment: Thats a lo .. i got a filter to work similar outside the Details view .. but when it is inside..thats a whole different thing. thanks again.